# Declare global variable in coffescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I use Gem Coocon for nested forms.

I need to hide the `#end_date_job_portfolio` field if `.checkBoxCurrentJob` is checked. The problem is that jQuery can`t see the tags if the user didn`t click **add new nested form** because these tags aren`t in `document` yet.

For this I use the `cocoon:after-insert`. This my script:

```
$(document).ready -> 
  checkbox_date = ""
  end_date = ""
  $('.experiences').on 'cocoon:after-insert', ->
    checkbox_date = $(".checkBoxCurrentJob")
    end_date = $('#end_date_job_portfolio') 
    console.log(checkbox_date)



  #show it when the checkbox is clicked
  сheckbox_date.on 'click', ->
    console.log("la la la")
    if checkbox_date.prop('checked')
      checkbox_date.hide()
    else
      checkbox_date.fadeIn()
    return
```

It displays `ReferenceError: \u0441heckbox_date is not defined` error. How do I pass `checkbox_date` and `end_date` values from `cocoon:after-insert` to the click event of `checkbox_date`?

Comment: Read the error message more carefully. Seems that you've typed a `\u0441` (which is a "Cyrillic small letter es") where you mean to type `c`. `\u0441` looks like a `c` but it isn't one.

Comment: @muistooshort you're right, the wrong line is that -> `сheckbox_date.on 'click',`, the wrong 'c' is there (`\u0441`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're probably referring to `\u{441}heckbox_date` (different identifier) instead of `checkbox_date` (as commented by @muistooshort though) at this line:

```
  сheckbox_date.on 'click', ->
  ^
```

This `с` should be the ASCII one. `c` (`\u{63}` or `\u0063`).

Additionally, from the ECMAScript language (on which JavaScript`s are based) specifications they recommend Unicode Normalised Form C to be applied in the language source codes (for each implementation), what I believe to solve this problem (I never cared and never did nothing about this though), but optional anyways.

Answer (score 1):

jquery has support for things that come in and out:

```
$(document).ready ->     
  #show it when the checkbox is clicked
  $(document).on 'click', ".checkBoxCurrentJob", ->
    console.log("la la la")
    checkbox_date = $(this)
    if checkbox_date.prop('checked')
      checkbox_date.hide()
    else
      checkbox_date.fadeIn()
    return
```